# How to prevent double click of "click" jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've this simple [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/wwgy8co6/) where if a user clicks `plus` glyphicon, I show the collapsed content and change the glyphicon to 'minus' and vice-versa on click of `minus`  glyphicon.

But, when I double click the `plus` glyphicon, the content shows and the glyphicon is not changed to `minus`. For the next single clicks, the content is shown when 'minus' glyphicon appears. How can I prevent the double click ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="divcontainer"> 
    <span>Click -----></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsecontent"></span>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapsecontent">
    content
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-plus').click(function () {
        $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon-plus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is. How you tried the solution from that question? $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".glyphicon-plus").one('click', function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           //do something
         $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon-plus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
});

Comment: @CristiC , i tried, but not working for this case. The - button is not changing back to + button

Comment: @CristiC check your fiddle properly, it's not changing the glyphicon for next clicks. Also, remove duplicate, so that I'll get the answer.

Comment: @CristiC in your fiddle too, it is not working

Comment: @Raviteja I added an answer. check it

Comment: Removed duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'onclick' function use collapse hide and show events. Please refer below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#collapsecontent').on('show.bs.collapse', function(args) {
    onContainerClick($(this).parent());
  });

  $('#collapsecontent').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(args) {
    onContainerClick($(this).parent());
  });
});

function onContainerClick(args) {
  $(args).find(".glyphicon-plus")
    .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `dblclick` event handler too

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-plus').click(function () {
        $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon-plus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
    $('.glyphicon-plus').dblclick(function () {
        $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon-plus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
});
```

```css
.divcontainer{
     background:aqua;
     width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="divcontainer"> 
    <span>Click -----></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsecontent"></span>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapsecontent">
    content
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, yes

Comment: yes. but maximum of double click event handlers are available

Answer (score 1):

just use your own jquery handler. Remove data-toggle attr and use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-plus').click(function () {
     $('.collapse').slideToggle();
     $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
});
```

I think it should work now.

Comment: toggling .glyphicon-plus is upon you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```